# How to transverse(?) table fields to become columns headers in a view in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have this, EAV approach:

```
Forms_data [id | form_id | survey_id | key  | value ]
           [1  | 1       | 1         | q1   |  Male ]
           [2  | 1       | 1         | q2   | 1/1/76]
           [3  | 2       | 1         | Car  |  Honda]
           [4  | 2       | 1         | Eng  | Petrol]
           [5  | 1       | 2         | q1   |  Fem  ]
           [6  | 1       | 2         | q2   | 2/3/81]
           [7  | 2       | 2         | Car  |  Ford ]
           [8  | 2       | 2         | Eng  | Diesel]
```

I would like to then create views, eg:

view form id 1:

```
[survey_id  |  q1   | q2     ]
[ 1         |  Male | 1/1/76 ] 
[ 2         |  Fem  | 2/3/81 ]
```

view form id 2:

```
[survey_id  |  car   | eng     ]
[ 1         |  Honda | Petrol  ] 
[ 2         |  Ford  | Diesel  ]
```

How would I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL does not have a PIVOT function to transform rows of data into columns, but you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result.

If you know the `key` values ahead of time, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select survey_id,
  max(case when `key`='q1' then value end) q1,
  max(case when `key`='q2' then value end) q2
from yt
where form_id = 1
group by survey_id;

select survey_id,
  max(case when `key`='car' then value end) car,
  max(case when `key`='eng' then value end) eng
from yt
where form_id = 2
group by survey_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc621f/2).

But if you want the result to be dynamic then you will need to use a prepared statement to get the result:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @form_id = 1;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN `key` = ''',
      `key`,
      ''' THEN value END) AS `',
      `key`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yt
where form_id = @form_id;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT survey_id, ', @sql, ' 
            from yt
            where form_id = ', @form_id, '
            group by survey_id');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc621f/6)